# Is it possible to abort jquery $.ajax request with data type json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want cancel jquery `$.ajax` call request with datatype json on window `unload` event. I tried doing this and it is throwing error on `xhr.abort();` line.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({         
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceUrl,
    dataType: "text json",
    data: ajaxParameters,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function(request, status, error) {
    },
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings) {                      
    }
});

$(window).onunload = function(){
    xhr.abort();
}
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error (missing comma after `serviceUrl`).  Also, it should be `$(window).on('beforeunload' ...)`

Comment: What's the error being thrown?

Comment: @AshokD Just curious, why would someone want to abort the request on window close? Won't it be automatically aborted?

Comment: @Салман not generally, no

Comment: @ExplosionPills didn't get you, what do you mean? aborting means we don't want response, and if we closing the browser, we anyways don't receive response.

Comment: @Салман but it doesn't halt the request on the server side

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/600494/1618713

Comment: just a side note to handle ajax requests I use ajaxQueue https://github.com/gnarf37/jquery-ajaxQueue , it has better way to manage requests in case you are sending lots of ajax requests to server and wants to avoid deadlock at serverside (specially session)

Comment: Here scenario is service call is made and IIS is processing it, between this client page is unloaded, now server sends the response and waits for client to send acknowledgement(Page is already unloaded so nobody is available to receive response). Because of this there are requests which are getting too much time in IIS logs, to avoid this I'm want the abort the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
// Global variable
var xhr;

xhr = $.ajax({         
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceUrl,
    dataType: "text json",
    data: ajaxParameters,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function(request, status, error) {
    },
    complete: function(e, xhr, settings) {                      
    }
});

$('body').on('beforeunload',function(){
    xhr.abort();
}
```

Comment: It is giving TypeError on   xhr.abort(); line

Comment: Try `console.log(xhr);` before abort line.

Comment: Before abort() call readyState was 1 and after abort() call readyState 0.

Comment: @AshokD Can you check at server side whether the request was aborted?

Comment: I can see through fiddler service returned with status code 200

Comment: Is it because we are using JSON datatype?

Comment: for JSONP it does not support, I think sameway for JSON it is not supporting

Comment: Just try `text`, what you get?

Comment: When I refresh the browser then I'm getting Syntax error on .abort() method. Did you have idea about this?

Comment: Browser refresh will invoke `onbeforeunload` before refreshing. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It gives error as "Syntax error" on abort call, if redirect to some other page then it does not throw any error

Comment: Which browser? Normally, you won't be able to see errors when you refresh and the browser clears all logs from previous session.

Comment: I'm using IE8. Tried using try catch and added alert in catch block.

Comment: Try Chrome, there the error will have a accompanying line number in the code, where the error occured.

Comment: have created chat room. Is it possible to join?

Comment: basically our requirement is to use IE8 only

Comment: What I am telling is trying in Chrome will give you more inputs on the errors.