# Send an AJAX event on beforeunload confirmation

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have a page where a person can query a large database (often can take half a minute or more). I want to do the following:

1. User tries to navigate away from page.
2. Show a dialogue confirming they wish to leave the page and lose their query progress. (Use `beforeunload`)
3. If the user clicks "confirm", then I want to kill the query (via AJAX) before allowing them to navigate away. (use unload, but how can I get the page to not exit before ajax completes?)

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Automatically abort AjaxRequests on Page Unload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600494/jquery-automatically-abort-ajaxrequests-on-page-unload)

Comment: Im not trying to abort an ajax request on page unload. I'm trying to send a *new* ajax request :)

Comment: The premise is the same though. Instead of sending the abort, send a new request.

Comment: But the page will unload before the ajax completes

Comment: Why does the query-killer need to return anything? Send the message to kill it and let them go on their way.

Comment: @DonnyP "kill the query (via AJAX)" led me to believe ...... :)

Comment: @phantom42 good point. thanks